# High stock avoid space between yAxis and first plot

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, highmaps

How to avoid space between yAxis and first plot

[image]

[image]

with Highchart it's working but with Highstock it's not working.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hymw04f/71/) `attached fiddle`

Comment: check in highstock http://jsfiddle.net/oze7r34c/

Comment: Thanks.. you guys are awesome. works perfect